# Any potential security risks with turning on relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping to allow URLs having part ending with '.'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

We are having an issue where our application fails when the URL has any part ending with '.' in it'; we can't avoid this due to functional requirements. The suggested solution is to turn on relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping in web.config file. We would like to know if there are any potential security risks with this approach.

Format of failing URL: http://server.com/path1/krishnakk./path2

It returns a 404 error.

Comment: What is the format of the url and why is the application failing?

Comment: Thanks Chris; I have updated my question with more details

Answer (score 15):

Even though this question is seven months old, here's an answer in case anyone else comes across a situation like this.

Regarding the security part of the question, by default `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` is set to false, and ASP .NET assumes that the path portion of a URL is a valid NTFS file path. If you disable this by setting `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` to true, then you are potentially opening your site up to attack because you're disabling the default protection provided by ASP .NET.

If you absolutely need to set `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` to true you should also be sure that you *validate all URLs within the constraints of your application's requirements*.

Comment: To save others some time, the above warnings by Hanselman (whom I respect highly) are unfortunately pretty non-specific, I might even say cargo-culting style. Like "this may void your warranty" and "better not do this but I won't say why". If there's a specific attack vector, mention it!...

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding the attack?

Comment: http://blog.detectify.com/post/82370846588/how-we-got-read-access-on-googles-production and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing explain one possible attack vector (although not specific to ASP.NET).

Comment: your first link is dead and how is the second link related to this setting? XXE has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but I thought I'd add what worked for me.

I just ran into this today, but fortunately was able to work around it. The solution was to pass the value that contained the dot (period) as part of the querystring, not the URL. You lose the elegance of having a clean URI without querystring, but it works without lowering security or changing any settings.

E.g. http://localhost/Home/hi.how:areyou will fail because it contains two illegal chars as part of the URI, the dot and the colon. However http://localhost/Home/id=hi.how:areyou will work perfectly.

Props to Scott Hanselman that, as always, will have blogged about pretty much all crazy scenarios and issues that one might run into while doing .NET development.

Answer (score 0):

There is no security risk [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.relaxedurltofilesystemmapping) about switching that `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` setting on.

This setting just looks to me as a way to disable an old legacy from times where IIS was primarily meant to serve files through HTTP and as such had built-in checks for rejecting queries which cannot be map to a file. See also this [blog](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/).

I agree that believing it is in any way security related and advising not to enable this is cargo-culting, like [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642623/any-potential-security-risks-with-turning-on-relaxedurltofilesystemmapping-to-al#comment41063495_14995282) by Roman Starkov.

Don't you think the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.relaxedurltofilesystemmapping) would mention it if there was any security risk associated with turning this on? Especially so long after having introduced it.

If you still consider this is unsafe, I urge you to [edit that documentation page](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/blob/main/xml/System.Web.Configuration/HttpRuntimeSection.xml) in order to add in it the missing warnings.